# How to include, build and debug shared libraries (.so) in vs code using cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, shared-libraries, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to debug catkin package node in vs code but I have encountered a problem. For some reason, in debug, mode program aborts when it needs to create object from a shared library.
When the program fails to create an object on call stack there are my shared libraries (.so) but vscode says that libraries have unknown source from what I can conclude that cmake or vscode do not know where shared libraries are located. Shared libraries are included in CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++14)

project(1_OpenCV_detection)

message(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
# Aggregate the sources
#file(GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.cpp")
set(SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Model.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Mesh.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/CsvReader.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/CsvWriter.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ModelRegistration.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/PnPProblem.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/RobustMatcher.cpp"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Utils.cpp")
message(${SOURCES})
#set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/share/OpenCV/")
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/")
#message(${OpenCV_DIR})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
  include
  ${opencv_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_DIR}
  /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/utils/
  /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/
  /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/
  /opt/ros/melodic/include/
  /usr/include/boost/
  #/usr/include/opencv/opencv2/
  #/usr/share/OpenCV/
  #linux
  /usr/include/c++/7/
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/
  /usr/include/c++/7/backward/
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/
  #/usr/local/include/
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed/
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
  /usr/include/
  /usr/local/lib/
)
add_library(opencv_so SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(
  opencv_so 
  PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.3
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.3
) 
## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
OpenCV REQUIRED
cv_bridge
image_transport
roscpp
sensor_msgs
std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES 1_OpenCV_detection
  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
add_executable(OpenCV_registration src/OpenCV_registration.cpp ${SOURCES} ${OpenCV_DIR})
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_registration ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS}  opencv_so)

add_executable(test_luka src/test.cpp ${SOURCES} ${OpenCV_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test_luka ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS}  opencv_so)
```

I have searched google upside down but I couldn't find any solution how to include shared libraries in my cmake that works for me.

I am trying to debug this small program:

```
// C++
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

// OpenCV
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utils/filesystem.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>

// PnP Tutorial
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Model.h"
#include "PnPProblem.h"
#include "RobustMatcher.h"
#include "ModelRegistration.h"
#include "Utils.h"

//ROS-->openCV
//bridge between ROS and opencv; used for reading from camera topic in ROS and giving it to opencv
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

/**  GLOBAL VARIABLES  **/

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/**  Functions headers  **/
void help();
void initKalmanFilter( KalmanFilter &KF, int nStates, int nMeasurements, int nInputs, double dt);
void predictKalmanFilter( KalmanFilter &KF, Mat &translation_predicted, Mat &rotation_predicted );
void updateKalmanFilter( KalmanFilter &KF, Mat &measurements,
                         Mat &translation_estimated, Mat &rotation_estimated );
void fillMeasurements( Mat &measurements,
                       const Mat &translation_measured, const Mat &rotation_measured);
string CurrentPath;
string getCurrentPath()
{
    size_t size;
        char *path=NULL;
    path=getcwd(path,size);
    CurrentPath=path;
    return path;
}
/**  Main program  **/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
    cout << "Current directory is: " << getCurrentPath() << endl;

    string video_read_path = samples::findFile("src/1_OpenCV_detection/Data/box.mp4");                             // recorded video
    string yml_read_path = samples::findFile("src/1_OpenCV_detection/Data/cube_30mm/cube_30mm.yml");               // 3dpts + descriptors
    string ply_read_path = samples::findFile("src/1_OpenCV_detection/Data/cube_30mm/meshes/cube_30mm.ply");        // object mesh

    Model model;                // instantiate Model object
    cout<<"Before model.load()"<<endl;
    model.load(yml_read_path); // load a 3D textured object model
    cout<<"After model.load()"<<endl;
    Mesh mesh;                 // instantiate Mesh object
    mesh.load(ply_read_path);  // load an object mesh

    return 0;
}
```

Program always fails with on same place, in method model.load(yml_read_path) and vscode raises popup window in right bottom corner which says:

> Unable to open 'strlen-avx2.S': Unable to read file
>   '/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S'
>   (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file
>   '/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S').

but my opinion is that there is no problem with strlen and that .so libraries are not included somehow.

Ignore all these include headers, I just copied them from another program but I am not using it in my test_luka.cpp

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have tried @Boris suggestion (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/811) but without any success, shared libraries are still unknown only difference is that after exception I program goes to strlen-avx2.S.

```
$ sudo apt install glibc-source 
$ cd /usr/src/glibc 
$ sudo tar xvf glibc-2.27.tar.xz
```

Then make link for folders using sourceFileMap in launch.json:

```
"sourceFileMap": {
    "/build/glibc-OTsEL5": "/usr/src/glibc"
},
```

When I run ldd in exe directory like this:

```
  ldd OpenCV_registration | grep libopencv_core
```

I get this output:

libopencv_core.so.3.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2 (0x00007f0f4d85e000)
libopencv_core.so.4.3 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.3 (0x00007f0f4bc62000)
So it seems to recognizes which libraries are needed but looks like doesn't know where to find them

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here, but the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
OpenCV REQUIRED ...` looks incorrect. There should only be one `REQUIRED` argument in the call. It is unclear how this may be affecting things, but I would think that will yield an error or warning.

Comment: @squareskittles thanks for answer I have changed it but it still doesn't recognize shared library. See my edit maybe there is another clue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the fix mentioned in vs-code's github bug reports https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/811

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error when I tried to use cv_bridge with an incompatible  version of OpenCV(I installed a higher version OpenCV using source install method), make sure that you are linking against OpenCV that is bundled with ROS version you use.